# xamarin forms zoomable image (Cross Platform)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to use pinch to zoom in shared Xamarin Forms, I only found an implementation for each platform.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Pan Gesture to implement it. 
There is a good sample of wrapping an image in PanContainer available here - [Adding a Pan Gesture Recognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pan/).

> The pan gesture is used for detecting dragging and is implemented with
>   the [PanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.PanGestureRecognizer/) class. A common scenario for the pan gesture
>   is to horizontally and vertically drag an image, so that all of the
>   image content can be viewed when it's being displayed in a viewport
>   smaller than the image dimensions. This is accomplished by moving the
>   image within the viewport.

Simple Example :

```
<Image Source="MonoMonkey.jpg">
  <Image.GestureRecognizers>
    <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="OnPanUpdated" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

Pan Container example XAML:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <local:PanContainer>
        <Image Source="MonoMonkey.jpg" WidthRequest="1024" HeightRequest="768" />
    </local:PanContainer>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Code behind :

```
public class PanContainer : ContentView
{
  double x, y;

  public PanContainer ()
  {
    // Set PanGestureRecognizer.TouchPoints to control the
    // number of touch points needed to pan
    var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer ();
    panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
    GestureRecognizers.Add (panGesture);
  }

 void OnPanUpdated (object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
 {
   switch (e.StatusType) {
   case GestureStatus.Running:
     // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
     Content.TranslationX =
      Math.Max (Math.Min (0, x + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs (Content.Width - App.ScreenWidth));
     Content.TranslationY =
      Math.Max (Math.Min (0, y + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs (Content.Height - App.ScreenHeight));
     break;

   case GestureStatus.Completed:
     // Store the translation applied during the pan
     x = Content.TranslationX;
     y = Content.TranslationY;
     break;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this modification](https://github.com/mahab339/Xamarin.Forms.PinchZoomImage/blob/container-for-maui/Xamarin.Forms.PinchZoomImage/Zoom.cs) I made and verified on .NET Maui to [TBertuzzi/Xamarin.Forms.PinchZoomImage](https://github.com/TBertuzzi/Xamarin.Forms.PinchZoomImage) to:

- Adjust image boundaries for not offsetting it while pan gesture.
- Sleep for .2 seconds after zoom for pan prevent.
- Do not zoom over 4 times.
  And it can be used as container like this after importing from appropriate namespace:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
 < ContentPage xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns: x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns: collects = "clr-namespace:Mab.Collects"
             x: Class = "N3ema.Secondpageimageshow" >
    < ContentPage.Content >
        < collects:Zoom >
            < collects:Zoom.Content >
                < StackLayout >
                    < Image Source = "shahid.jpeg"
                           HorizontalOptions = "Fill"
                           Aspect = "Fill"
                           VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" />
                </ StackLayout >
            </ collects:Zoom.Content >
        </ collects:Zoom >
    </ ContentPage.Content >
</ ContentPage >
```